# Operand type clash : varchar(255) encrypted is incompatible with varchar - Stored procedure with Upper - Always Encrypted

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working with Always Encrypted SQL Server and C# program.

When I call a stored procedure (this SP not needs to pass any parameters), I get an operand type clash `varchar(255)`.

When I go back to my SSMS, I remove the calling Encrypted column from my request and everything is OK, when I add again the encrypted column, I get the error again and again.

Here the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
select 
UPPER(u_nom) from 
Utilisateur
END GO
```

and this the error what I get:

> Operand type clash : varchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyBase') collation_name = 'French_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar

and how I encrypted the column enter image description here

[image]

Comment: encryption&decryption at the client. Try without the upper() on the encrypted column

Comment: thanks for you anwser. of course, I try without upper fonction, it was ok. that's why I write this post. the stored procedure is called by my client : MSSMS or .net code , so ... what's the prob ? :)